# Create a script or task to modify database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I need to create a script that imports data from a file system source. How do I do that?

I already tried to create a rake task but there the models are not loaded. How do I get the whole rails environment into my task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
desc 'Do stuff with models'
task :do_stuff => :environment do
  1000.times.each do |i|
    Model.create :name => "model number #{i}"
  end
end
```

You declare `:environment` as a dependency of your rake task.  This loads up rails and all of your app code before it runs.

Comment: Thanks. Yes at least my model Foo is recognized now. But when I say `Foo.make({...})` I get: `undefined method \`make' for #<Class:0x7f1b66022cd0>`

Comment: `make` is not a class method provided by `ActiveRecord`.  So did you add a class method called `make` to your model class?

Comment: Yeah, it's a convenience method defined in the testing environment (spec...)